# Review queue bugged?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Last few days the review queue has been a bit buggy for me. Latest example, today I got notice of 8 review things (orange cube next to review). And after reviewing 3 First post's I had nothing left in the review tab, but the orange cube remains at 5.

Is this some sort of bug/glitch? Attempted refreshing, re-logging, clearing cache. But it kept persisting.

[image]

Comment: If this is tagged as [meta-tag:bug], shouldn't it be [meta-tag:status-bydesign] rather than [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indicator tells how many review tasks there are overall. And not how many you can still act on.

This is answered in detail **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231052/166899)**.